# A question about improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Would you please give me a hint on how to solve this problem:

Suppose $f(x)$ continuous in $[0,\infty)$ and for each $a,b>0$ and $c>b$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
ab \left|\int_0^1 f\left(ax+c \right) dx \right|<1.
\end{equation*}
Prove that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges. I do not understand how to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint : try to express $\int_x^y f(t)dt$ with respect to $\int_0^1 f(\ldots)dx$ using affine variable change

Comment: Make the change of variables $y=ax+c$. The bounds of integration also change.

Comment: Well,from $\left|\int_c^{c+a}f(y)dy\right|<\frac 1b$ we can conclude that for all c>b>N $\int_c^{c+a}f(y)dy \to 0$, threrefore our integral is Cauchy, is not it ?

Comment: @user97484 Yes you got it, since $b$ ranges from $0$ to $c$, you have $| \int_c^{c+a} f| \geq \frac{1}{c}$ when $b$ goes to $c$, and the integral is indeed Cauchy

Comment: Sorry, read $|\int_c^{c+a}f| \leq \frac{1}{c}$

Answer (score 0):

We have for all $a,b,c$ with $0 <a,b$ and $b < c$ that $$
  \left|\int_{0}^1 f(ax + c) \,dx \right| < \frac{1}{ab}
$$
Set $u = ax + c$, then $\frac{du}{dx} = a$ and $$
  \left|\frac{1}{a} \int_c^{c+a} f(u) \,du\right| = \left|\int_{0}^1 f(ax + c) \,dx \right| < \frac{1}{ab} \text{.}
$$

If you fix $c=1$, $b=\frac{1}{2}$ this yields $$
  \left|\int_1^{1+a} f(u) \,du\right| < 2 \quad\Rightarrow\quad \lim_{a\to\infty} \left|\int_1^{a} f(u) \,du\right| < 2 \text{.}
$$
Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, you can assume $\int_0^1 f(x) \,d$ converges, and then you're done.

Comment: How do you get the existence of the limit ?